# Excel VBA now with a new column, but then it stops

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel VBA where I try to make the opportunity for discount II, but i only get error message.
The error message says I can't add SET clause to another SET clause.
Is there anyone who can see what I'm doing wrong.

****(All associated **Discount II** is what I have added in the second code)****

Here is the old vba:

```html
Private Sub cmdUpdateStockSurvey_Click()

    Dim SQL As String
    Dim bolRetVal As Boolean
    Dim lRow As Integer
    
    Dim RST As ADODB.Recordset
    
    Dim lSeqNo As Long
    Dim lPriceListNo As String
    Dim lDiscountType As Integer
    Dim lArticleNo As String
    Dim lAgreedPrice As String
    Dim lDiscountI As String
    Dim lCurrencyNo As String
    
    Dim lStartDate As String
    Dim lStopDate As String
    Dim lDateValue As Date
    
    '\\her deklareres variablene som skal leses inn
    lPriceListNo = ActiveSheet.Range("B3")
    
    If Not IsNumeric(lPriceListNo) Then
        MsgBox "Prislistenummer i celle B3 er ikke gyldig!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If LogOnGlobal = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'On Error GoTo Feil
    lDiscountType = 10 'kode for prisliste
    lSeqNo = GetLastNo("SeqNo", mCatalog, lPriceListNo) + 10000
    
    '\\startdate
    If IsDate(ActiveSheet.Range("B4")) Then
        lDateValue = ActiveSheet.Range("B4")
        lStartDate = Replace(Format(lDateValue, "mm.dd.yyyy"), ".", "/")
    Else
        MsgBox "Startdato i celle B4 er ikke gyldig!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    '\\stopdate
    If IsDate(ActiveSheet.Range("B5")) Then
        lDateValue = ActiveSheet.Range("B5")
        lStopDate = Replace(Format(lDateValue, "mm.dd.yyyy"), ".", "/")
    Else
        MsgBox "Stoppdato i celle B5 er ikke gyldig!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    lRow = 8
    lArticleNo = Replace(Replace(ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 1), " ", ""), "'", "''", , , vbTextCompare)
    
    Do Until ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 1) = ""
        
        Application.StatusBar = "Skriver rad: " & lRow & ", artikkel: " & lArticleNo
        
        'Legger innhold i cellene inn i variabler
        lArticleNo = Replace(Replace(ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 1), " ", ""), "'", "''", , , vbTextCompare)
     
        If lArticleNo = "" Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        
        lAgreedPrice = ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 3)
        
        If Not IsNumeric(lAgreedPrice) Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 6) = "Avtalt pris ikke gyldig"
            GoTo Neste
        End If
        
        lCurrencyNo = ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 4)
        
        If Not IsNumeric(lCurrencyNo) Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 6) = "Valutanr. ikke gyldig"
            GoTo Neste
        End If
        
        lDiscountI = ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 5)
        
        If Not IsNumeric(lDiscountI) Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 6) = "Rabatt1 ikke gyldig"
            GoTo Neste
        End If
        
        '\\Sjekker om det artikkel finnes i artikkelregisteret
        SQL = "SELECT ArticleNo FROM " & mOwner & ".Article"
        SQL = SQL & " WHERE ArticleNo = '" & lArticleNo & "'"
        
        Set RST = New ADODB.Recordset
        RST.Open SQL, mCON, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
        
        If RST.EOF = False Then
            
            SQL = "INSERT INTO " & mOwner & ".DiscountAgreementCustomer(SeqNo,PriceListNo ,DiscountType,ArticleNo,AgreedPrice,DiscountI,CurrencyNo,"
            SQL = SQL & " StartDate , StopDate, Created, LastUpdate, LastUpdatedBy, CreatedBy"
            SQL = SQL & ",BonusPercent,DiscountII,DiscountIII,CustomerNo,DiscountGrpArtNo,DiscountGrpCustNo,FromQuantity,GrossPrice,IntermediateGroupNo,LoanPrice,MainGroupNo,Markup1,SubGroupNo,ToQuantity,UnitTypeNo,ProjectNo,Priority,PriceLabeled)"
            
            SQL = SQL & " VALUES(" & lSeqNo & "," & lPriceListNo & "," & lDiscountType & ",'" & lArticleNo & "'," & Replace(lAgreedPrice, ",", ".") & ","
            SQL = SQL & Replace(lDiscountI, ",", ".") & "," & Replace(lCurrencyNo, ",", ".") & ",'" & lStartDate & "','" & lStopDate & "',getdate(),getdate(),1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)"
            
            Debug.Print SQL
            mCON.Execute SQL
                  
            lSeqNo = lSeqNo + 10000
            ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 6) = "OK"
            
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 6) = "Artikkelnr ikke gyldig"
              
        End If
        
Neste:
        lRow = lRow + 1
        Application.StatusBar = "Behandler rad: " & lRow
        
            
    Loop
    
    MsgBox "Ferdig!" & vbLf & vbLf & "Kontroller Status-kollone ang. feil.", vbInformation
    Application.StatusBar = False
    
    Exit Sub
    
Feil:
    MsgBox "Det er oppstått en feil!" & vbLf & vbLf & "Feilnr: " & Err.Number & vbLf & "Beskrivelse: " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    


End Sub

Private Function GetLastNo(iNextWhat As String, iDB As String, Optional iWHERE As String) As String

    Dim SQL As String
    Dim RST As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim lNextID As String

    Select Case iNextWhat
    
        Case "UniqueNo"
            SQL = "SELECT MAX(UniqueID) as LastID FROM " & iDB & "." & mOwner & ".DiscountAgreementCustomer"
            
            Set RST = New ADODB.Recordset
            
            RST.Open SQL, mCON, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
            
            If RST.EOF = False Then
                If Not IsNull(RST!LastID) Then
                    lNextID = Val(RST!LastID)
                Else
                    lNextID = 0
                End If
            Else
                lNextID = 0
            End If
        
        
        Case "SeqNo"
            SQL = "SELECT MAX(SeqNo) as LastID FROM " & iDB & "." & mOwner & ".DiscountAgreementCustomer"
            SQL = SQL & " WHERE PriceListNo = " & iWHERE
            
            Set RST = New ADODB.Recordset
            RST.Open SQL, mCON, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
            
            If RST.EOF = False Then
                If Not IsNull(RST!LastID) Then
                    lNextID = Val(RST!LastID)
                Else
                    lNextID = 10000000
                End If
            Else
                lNextID = 10000000
            End If
        
    End Select
    
    GetLastNo = lNextID
    
End Function
```

And here's where i get error message (edited)

```html
Private Sub cmdUpdateStockSurvey_Click()

    Dim SQL As String
    Dim bolRetVal As Boolean
    Dim lRow As Integer
    
    Dim RST As ADODB.Recordset
    
    Dim lSeqNo As Long
    Dim lPriceListNo As String
    Dim lDiscountType As Integer
    Dim lArticleNo As String
    Dim lAgreedPrice As String
    Dim lDiscountI As String
    Dim lDiscountII As String
    Dim lCurrencyNo As String
    
    Dim lStartDate As String
    Dim lStopDate As String
    Dim lDateValue As Date
    
    '\\her deklareres variablene som skal leses inn
    lPriceListNo = ActiveSheet.Range("B3")
    
    If Not IsNumeric(lPriceListNo) Then
        MsgBox "Prislistenummer i celle B3 er ikke gyldig!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If LogOnGlobal = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'On Error GoTo Feil
    lDiscountType = 10 'kode for prisliste
    lSeqNo = GetLastNo("SeqNo", mCatalog, lPriceListNo) + 10000
    
    '\\startdate
    If IsDate(ActiveSheet.Range("B4")) Then
        lDateValue = ActiveSheet.Range("B4")
        lStartDate = Replace(Format(lDateValue, "mm.dd.yyyy"), ".", "/")
    Else
        MsgBox "Startdato i celle B4 er ikke gyldig!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    '\\stopdate
    If IsDate(ActiveSheet.Range("B5")) Then
        lDateValue = ActiveSheet.Range("B5")
        lStopDate = Replace(Format(lDateValue, "mm.dd.yyyy"), ".", "/")
    Else
        MsgBox "Stoppdato i celle B5 er ikke gyldig!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    lRow = 9
    lArticleNo = Replace(Replace(ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 1), " ", ""), "'", "''", , , vbTextCompare)
    
    Do Until ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 1) = ""
        
        Application.StatusBar = "Skriver rad: " & lRow & ", artikkel: " & lArticleNo
        
        'Legger innhold i cellene inn i variabler
        lArticleNo = Replace(Replace(ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 1), " ", ""), "'", "''", , , vbTextCompare)
     
        If lArticleNo = "" Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        
        lAgreedPrice = ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 3)
        
        If Not IsNumeric(lAgreedPrice) Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 7) = "Avtalt pris ikke gyldig"
            GoTo Neste
        End If
        
        lCurrencyNo = ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 4)
        
        If Not IsNumeric(lCurrencyNo) Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 7) = "Valutanr. ikke gyldig"
            GoTo Neste
        End If
        
        lDiscountI = ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 5)
        
        If Not IsNumeric(lDiscountI) Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 7) = "Rabatt1 ikke gyldig"
            GoTo Neste
        End If
                
        lDiscountII = ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 6)
        
        If Not IsNumeric(lDiscountII) Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 7) = "Rabatt2 ikke gyldig"
            GoTo Neste
        End If
        
        '\\Sjekker om det artikkel finnes i artikkelregisteret
        SQL = "SELECT ArticleNo FROM " & mOwner & ".Article"
        SQL = SQL & " WHERE ArticleNo = '" & lArticleNo & "'"
        
        Set RST = New ADODB.Recordset
        RST.Open SQL, mCON, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
        
        If RST.EOF = False Then
            
            SQL = "INSERT INTO " & mOwner & ".DiscountAgreementCustomer(SeqNo,PriceListNo ,DiscountType,ArticleNo,AgreedPrice,DiscountI,DiscountII,CurrencyNo,"
            SQL = SQL & " StartDate , StopDate, Created, LastUpdate, LastUpdatedBy, CreatedBy"
            SQL = SQL & ",BonusPercent,DiscountII,DiscountIII,CustomerNo,DiscountGrpArtNo,DiscountGrpCustNo,FromQuantity,GrossPrice,IntermediateGroupNo,LoanPrice,MainGroupNo,Markup1,SubGroupNo,ToQuantity,UnitTypeNo,ProjectNo,Priority,PriceLabeled)"
            
            SQL = SQL & " VALUES(" & lSeqNo & "," & lPriceListNo & "," & lDiscountType & ",'" & lArticleNo & "'," & Replace(lAgreedPrice, ",", ".") & ","
            SQL = SQL & Replace(lDiscountI, ",", ".") & "," & Replace(lDiscountII, ",", ".") & "," & Replace(lCurrencyNo, ",", ".") & ",'" & lStartDate & "','" & lStopDate & "',getdate(),getdate(),1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)"
            
            Debug.Print SQL
            mCON.Execute SQL
                  
            lSeqNo = lSeqNo + 10000
            ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 7) = "OK"
            
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 7) = "Artikkelnr ikke gyldig"
              
        End If
        
Neste:
        lRow = lRow + 1
        Application.StatusBar = "Behandler rad: " & lRow
        
            
    Loop
    
    MsgBox "Ferdig!" & vbLf & vbLf & "Kontroller Status-kollone ang. feil.", vbInformation
    Application.StatusBar = False
    
    Exit Sub
    
Feil:
    MsgBox "Det er oppstått en feil!" & vbLf & vbLf & "Feilnr: " & Err.Number & vbLf & "Beskrivelse: " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    


End Sub

Private Function GetLastNo(iNextWhat As String, iDB As String, Optional iWHERE As String) As String

    Dim SQL As String
    Dim RST As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim lNextID As String

    Select Case iNextWhat
    
        Case "UniqueNo"
            SQL = "SELECT MAX(UniqueID) as LastID FROM " & iDB & "." & mOwner & ".DiscountAgreementCustomer"
            
            Set RST = New ADODB.Recordset
            
            RST.Open SQL, mCON, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
            
            If RST.EOF = False Then
                If Not IsNull(RST!LastID) Then
                    lNextID = Val(RST!LastID)
                Else
                    lNextID = 0
                End If
            Else
                lNextID = 0
            End If
        
        
        Case "SeqNo"
            SQL = "SELECT MAX(SeqNo) as LastID FROM " & iDB & "." & mOwner & ".DiscountAgreementCustomer"
            SQL = SQL & " WHERE PriceListNo = " & iWHERE
            
            Set RST = New ADODB.Recordset
            RST.Open SQL, mCON, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
            
            If RST.EOF = False Then
                If Not IsNull(RST!LastID) Then
                    lNextID = Val(RST!LastID)
                Else
                    lNextID = 10000000
                End If
            Else
                lNextID = 10000000
            End If
        
    End Select
    
    GetLastNo = lNextID
    
End Function
```

Here is a picture of how ark1 looks
[image]

And after:
[image]

Error code:

[image]

Comment: `LogOnGlobal` , `mCatalog` variables are not defined. There may be other ones also. As a first step please check that all variables are properly defined.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
But forgot to say that "the old vba" works. (without discount II)
But that's when I add discount II it stops.

Comment: please include `Option Explicit` in your program and then check. That is a standard way. When I checked with `Option Explicit` first 2 points of concern which came up , were informed to you. In such a review one can not proceed further unless faulty points are corrected..

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I have `Option Explicit` at my first line :P